# Resample time series after removing top x percentile data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an hourly time series data (say df with date/time and value columns) where I want to:

Step 1: Remove the top 5 percentile of each day

Step 2: Get the max(Step 1)for each day

Step 3: Get the mean(Step 2) for each month

Here is what I have tried to implement the above logic:

```
step_1 = df.resample('D').apply(lambda x: x<x.quantile(0.95))
step_2 = step_1.resample('D').max()
step_3 = step_2.resample('M').mean()
```

Even though I do not get any code error, the generated output is different to the expected result based on the above 3 steps (I always get a constant value)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Your `step_1` is a series of booleans with the same index as the original data, you can use it to filter your DataFrame, thus:

```py
step_1 = df.resample('D').apply(lambda x: x<x.quantile(0.95))
step_2 = df[step_1].resample('D').max()
step_3 = step_2.resample('M').mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is a boolean mask, so you need to add an additional step:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', periods=1000, freq='H'), columns=['my_data'])

mask = df.resample('D').apply(lambda x: x < x.quantile(.95))

step_1 = df[mask]

step_2 = df.resample('D').max()

step_3 = df.resample('M').mean()
```